# Different between flex-driection columns and rows in flexbox

Tags: flexbox

Please I am new to css and i want to know the different between flex-driection rows and columns. I have tried reading some resources but not getting the hang of it.  I need someone to explain to me like in  a layman language.

Answer (score 1):

The flex-direction property in CSS is used to specify the direction in which flex items are laid out inside a flex container. There are two main values for flex-direction: row and column. Let's explore the differences between these two options:

flex-direction: row:

The default value for flex-direction.
Flex items are positioned horizontally in a single row.
The main axis runs horizontally from left to right.
The cross axis runs vertically from top to bottom.
Flex items are laid out side by side, starting from the beginning of the main axis and flowing towards the end.
flex-direction: column:

Flex items are positioned vertically in a single column.